# C++ lower_bound() to search for the closest element to a target value

Tags: c++, binary-search, lower-bound

Suppose I have a `vector`, the element of which is of `int` type. How do I elegantly use `std::lower_bound()` to look for the closest element to a target value?

I wrote codes as shown below:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> vec {3,4,5,10};
    int target = 6;

    auto found {
        lower_bound(
            vec.begin(),
            vec.end(),
            target,
            [=] (int ele1, int ele2) {
                return (abs(ele1 - target) > abs(ele2 - target));
            }
        )
    };

    cout << (found-vec.begin()) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It returns index of `4`, which means `found = vec.end()`. Instead, I want to get index of `2`. Where did I mess up?

Comment: `lower_bound` requires the contents of the container being searched to be ***ordered according to the comparison function*** which is not true in this case, as such the shown code is undefined behavior.

Comment: If `vec` is ordered and large, using interval bisection, Newton's method or (my favorite in terms of convergence properties and guarantees) Ridder's method may be useful.

Comment: Why do you want to use `lower_bound`?  It doesn't seem like a good tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a different predicate in `lower_bound` than is used for the sorting of `vec`. So your code snippet has undefined behavior.

You can still use `lower_bound` to simply look for `target`.

```
auto attempt = lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), target);
```

Now the iterator you are actually looking for is going to be either the iterator returned, or the iterator to the next element:

```
auto found = attempt == vec.end() ? 
             vec.end() - 1 :   // last element is closest
             attempt == vec.begin() ? 
             vec.begin() :  // first element is closest
             abs(*attempt - target) < abs(*(attempt - 1) - target) ? 
             // somewhere in the middle, then the previous element could be closer
             attempt : attempt - 1;
```

This assumes that `vec` is non-empty, so you may need to do that check as well.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/XfgVrU).

Comment: I tested this solution with OP's data and it said 10 was the closest number.  (found-vec.begin() was 3 and *found was 10.)  I may be missing something, but this doesn't seem right.

Comment: @DennisSparrow edited, I needed to check the iterator before instead. Thanks for the correction.